# making a copy of panel with all its control

Tags: c#, asp.net, copy, clone

I am working on a project,I want to generate a receipt having three copies-student copy,accounts copy,office copy.All these copies will have the same data except the heading.So what i have done is generated a panel and populating it and have made three different divs for three copies.Now at backend after populating the panel i am making three panels at runtime with different names and passing this panel to them and then adding the three panels to their respective div.By doing this i am getting the receipt only once and that to in the last div.Please help me how i can achieve this.

Code

```
public void generatereceipt()
{ //pnlreceipt is the main panel built in aspx page
    divstudent.Controls.Add(pnlreceipt);
    divpnlreceipt.Visible = true;
    divstudent.Visible = true;
    divoffice.Visible = true;
    divaccounts.Visible = true;
    Panel pnlstudent = new Panel();
    pnlstudent = pnlreceipt;
    divstudent.Controls.Add(pnlstudent);
    Panel pnloffice = new Panel();
    pnloffice = pnlreceipt;
    divoffice.Controls.Add(pnloffice);
    Panel pnlaccounts = new Panel();
    pnlaccounts = pnlreceipt;
    divaccounts.Controls.Add(pnlaccounts);
    divoffice.Visible = true;
    divaccounts.Visible = true;
}
//method to fill my panel receipt
public void filldata()
{
    sql ="select s.admissionnumber,s.studentname,g.forename,g.relationshipcode,c.classname,concat(a.address,',',a.town,',',a.state,',',a.country) as address,e.amount "
        +"from tblstudent s left join tblguardian g on s.studentcode=g.studentcode "
        +"left join tblclass c on c.classcode=s.classcode "
        +"left join tblcontactaddress ca on ca.usercode=g.guardiancode "
        +"left join tbladdress a on ca.addressid=a.addressid "
        +"left join tblmiddaymeal_entry e on e.studentcode=s.studentcode "
        +"where s.studentcode='"+drpstudent.SelectedItem.Value+"' and c.classcode='"+drpclass.SelectedItem.Value+"'";
    ds = obj.openDataset(sql,Session["schoolcode"].ToString());
    lblfathername.Text = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;i++)
    {
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["relationshipcode"].ToString()=="14")
        {
            lblfathername.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["forename"].ToString();
        }
    }
    string sqlrecepit = "SELECT * FROM tblmiddaymeal_receipt order by receiptno desc";
    DataSet dsreceipt = new DataSet();
    dsreceipt = obj.openDataset(sqlrecepit,Session["schoolcode"].ToString());
    string sqlschool = "select * from tblschool where schoolcode='"+Session["schoolcode"].ToString()+"'";
    DataSet dsSchool = new DataSet();
    dsSchool = obj.openDataset(sqlschool,Session["schoolcode"].ToString());
    if (dsreceipt.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        lblreceiptno.Text = "10000";
    }
    else
    {
        lblreceiptno.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(dsreceipt.Tables[0].Rows[0]["receiptno"]) + 1).ToString();
    }
    lblreceiptcopy.Text = "Student Copy";
    lbladmno.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["admissionnumber"].ToString();
    lblcodeno.Text = "";
    lbldate.Text = "<b>"+DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")+"</b>";
    lblname.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["studentname"].ToString();
    lblclass.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["classname"].ToString();
    lblmonth.Text = monthdisplay;
    lblschool.Text = dsSchool.Tables[0].Rows[0]["schoolname"].ToString();
    lblbranch.Text = "S.S.B";
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["amount"].ToString().Length == 0)
    {
        lblamount.Text = "";
        lbltotalamount.Text = "";
        lblamountwords.Text = "";
    }
    else
    {
        lblamount.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["amount"].ToString();
        lbltotalamount.Text = "<b>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["amount"].ToString() + "</b>";
        lblamountwords.Text = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + "<b>" + NumberToWords(Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["amount"])) + "&nbsp;only" + " </b>";
    }        
    lblpaymenttype.Text = drppayment.SelectedItem.Text;
    if(drppayment.SelectedIndex==2)
    {
        lblbankname.Text = txtbankname.Text;
    }
    string sqlinsert = "insert into tblmiddaymeal_receipt(receiptno,studentcode,date,forMonthOf,branch,amount,paymenttype,bankname) "
                 + "values('" + lblreceiptno.Text + "','" + drpstudent.SelectedItem.Value + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "','" + months + "','" + lblbranch.Text + "','" + lblamount.Text + "','" + lblpaymenttype.Text + "','" + lblbankname.Text + "')";
    obj.executeQuery(sqlinsert, Session["schoolcode"].ToString());
}
```

My panel receipt structure and three divs-student,account and office in aspx page

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlreceipt" runat="server">
    <div id="divprint">
    <div id="divpnlreceipt" runat="server" visible="false">
    <table class="outertable">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Image ID="imglogo" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/scholar-logo.png" CssClass="logo"/>
                <asp:Label ID="lblreceiptcopy" runat="server" Text="Label" CssClass="receiptcopyheading"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class="innertablereceipt">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4"><span class="innerheading">ME-LUNCH RECEIPT</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Receipt No:<asp:Label ID="lblreceiptno" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Adm. No:<asp:Label ID="lbladmno" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="col3">
                            Code No:<asp:Label ID="lblcodeno" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Date:<asp:Label ID="lbldate" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Name:<asp:Label ID="lblname" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Class:<asp:Label ID="lblclass" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            For the month of:<asp:Label ID="lblmonth" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Father's Name:<asp:Label ID="lblfathername" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            School:<asp:Label ID="lblschool" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            Branch:<asp:Label ID="lblbranch" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Address:<asp:Label ID="lbladdress" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="height:4px;">
                        <td colspan="4">................................................................................................................................................................................................</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="border-bottom:1px dotted black;">
                        <td colspan="2">
                            Particulars
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Amount
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr style="height:4px;">
                        <td colspan="4">................................................................................................................................................................................................</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="border-bottom:1px dotted black;height:40px">
                        <td colspan="2">
                            Me-Lunch Charges
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblamount" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr style="height:4px;">
                        <td colspan="4">................................................................................................................................................................................................</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3"></td>
                        <td>
                            Total amount:<asp:Label ID="lbltotalamount" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Cash/cheque No:<asp:Label ID="lblpaymenttype" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            Bank Name:<asp:Label ID="lblbankname" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>(In words):</td>
                        <td colspan="2" class="txtunderline">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblamountwords" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            *Cheque subject to realisation
                        </td>
                        <td>Cashier Signature</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
        </div>
</asp:Panel>
<div id="divstudent" runat="server" class="studentreceipt" visible="false">div1</div>
<div id="divoffice" runat="server" class="officereceipt" visible="false">div2</div>
<div id="divaccounts" runat="server" class="accountsreceipt" visible="false">div3</div>
```

output receipt i want

[image]

Comment: create a userControl.

Comment: will creating a usercontrol solve my problem,I mean i will have to bind data thrice or once only as i want,can you please elaborate more so that i can try this solution

Comment: `All these copies will have the same data except the heading`. So you only need to pull the data once. Expose the heading as a property that you can update from your code.

Comment: but i have to bind data depending on user selection so how I can bind data in usercontrol because those dropdown will not be available on usercontrol page,please explain

Comment: have a look at this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3457w616(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: okk i will try this also but just tell me is it possible by using repeater control also,if yes just give me a hint how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I placed my pnlreceipt inside a repeater and it solved my problem i am pasting my code

Aspx code of repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptreceipt" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptreceipt_OnItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlreceipt" runat="server">
    <div  runat="server">
    <div id="divpnlreceipt" runat="server">
    <table id="tblreceipt" class="outertable" runat="server">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Image ID="imglogo" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/scholar-logo.png" CssClass="logo"/>
                <asp:Label ID="lblreceiptcopy" runat="server" Text="Label" CssClass="receiptcopyheading"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class="innertablereceipt">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4"><span class="innerheading">ME-LUNCH     RECEIPT</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Receipt No:<asp:Label ID="lblreceiptno" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Adm. No:<asp:Label ID="lbladmno" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="col3">
                            Code No:<asp:Label ID="lblcodeno" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Date:<asp:Label ID="lbldate" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Name:<asp:Label ID="lblname" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Class:<asp:Label ID="lblclass" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            For the month of:<asp:Label ID="lblmonth" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Father's Name:<asp:Label ID="lblfathername" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            School:<asp:Label ID="lblschool" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            Branch:<asp:Label ID="lblbranch" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Address:<asp:Label ID="lbladdress" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="height:4px;">
                        <td colspan="4">................................................................................................................................................................................................</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="border-bottom:1px dotted black;">
                        <td colspan="2">
                            Particulars
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Amount
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr style="height:4px;">
                        <td colspan="4">................................................................................................................................................................................................</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="border-bottom:1px dotted black;height:40px">
                        <td colspan="2">
                            Me-Lunch Charges
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblamount" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr style="height:4px;">
                        <td colspan="4">................................................................................................................................................................................................</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3"></td>
                        <td>
                            Total amount:<asp:Label ID="lbltotalamount" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Cash/cheque No:<asp:Label ID="lblpaymenttype" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            Bank Name:<asp:Label ID="lblbankname" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>(In words):</td>
                        <td colspan="2" class="txtunderline">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblamountwords" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            *Cheque subject to realisation
                        </td>
                        <td>Cashier Signature</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
        </div>
</asp:Panel>
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

C# code

```
public void filldata()
{
    int[] a=new int[]{0,1,2};
    rptreceipt.DataSource = a;
    rptreceipt.DataBind();
}
public void rptreceipt_OnItemDataBound(object sender,RepeaterItemEventArgs e) 
{
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
sql = "select s.admissionnumber,s.studentname,g.forename,g.relationshipcode,c.classname,concat(a.address,',',a.town,',',a.state,',',a.country) as address,e.amount "
        + "from tblstudent s left join tblguardian g on s.studentcode=g.studentcode "
        + "left join tblclass c on c.classcode=s.classcode "
        + "left join tblcontactaddress ca on ca.usercode=g.guardiancode "
        + "left join tbladdress a on ca.addressid=a.addressid "
        + "left join tblmiddaymeal_entry e on e.studentcode=s.studentcode "
        + "where s.studentcode='" + drpstudent.SelectedItem.Value + "' and c.classcode='" + drpclass.SelectedItem.Value + "'";
    ds = obj.openDataset(sql, Session["schoolcode"].ToString());

   Label lblreceiptcopy=(Label) e.Item.FindControl("lblreceiptcopy");
   Label lblreceiptno = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblreceiptno");
   Label lbladmno = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lbladmno");
   Label lblcodeno = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblcodeno");
   Label lbldate = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lbldate");
   Label lblname = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblname");
   Label lblclass = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblclass");
   Label lblmonth = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblmonth");
   Label lblfathername = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblfathername");
   Label lblschool = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblschool");
   Label lblbranch = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblbranch");
   Label lbladdress = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lbladdress");
   Label lblamount = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblamount");
   Label lbltotalamount = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lbltotalamount");
   Label lblpaymenttype = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblpaymenttype");
   Label lblbankname = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblbankname");
   Label lblamountwords = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblamountwords");

   if (e.Item.ItemIndex == 0)
       lblreceiptcopy.Text = "Student Copy";
    else if (e.Item.ItemIndex == 1)
       lblreceiptcopy.Text = "Office Copy";
   else
       lblreceiptcopy.Text = "Accounts Copy";

    lblfathername.Text = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["relationshipcode"].ToString() == "14")
        {
            lblfathername.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["forename"].ToString();
        }
    }
    string sqlrecepit = "SELECT * FROM tblmiddaymeal_receipt order by receiptno desc";
    DataSet dsreceipt = new DataSet();
    dsreceipt = obj.openDataset(sqlrecepit, Session["schoolcode"].ToString());
    string sqlschool = "select * from tblschool where schoolcode='" + Session["schoolcode"].ToString() + "'";
    DataSet dsSchool = new DataSet();
    dsSchool = obj.openDataset(sqlschool, Session["schoolcode"].ToString());
    if (dsreceipt.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        lblreceiptno.Text = "10000";
    }
    else
    {
        lblreceiptno.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(dsreceipt.Tables[0].Rows[0]["receiptno"]) + 1).ToString();
    }
    //lblreceiptcopy.Text = "Student Copy";
    lbladmno.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["admissionnumber"].ToString();
    lblcodeno.Text = "";
    lbldate.Text = "<b>" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "</b>";
    lblname.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["studentname"].ToString();
    lblclass.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["classname"].ToString();
    lblmonth.Text = monthdisplay;
    lblschool.Text = dsSchool.Tables[0].Rows[0]["schoolname"].ToString();
    lblbranch.Text = "S.S.B";
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["amount"].ToString().Length == 0)
    {
        lblamount.Text = "";
        lbltotalamount.Text = "";
        lblamountwords.Text = "";
    }
    else
    {
        lblamount.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["amount"].ToString();
        lbltotalamount.Text = "<b>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["amount"].ToString() + "</b>";
        lblamountwords.Text = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + "<b>" + NumberToWords(Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["amount"])) + "&nbsp;only" + " </b>";
    }
    lblpaymenttype.Text = drppayment.SelectedItem.Text;
    if (drppayment.SelectedIndex == 2)
    {
        lblbankname.Text = txtbankname.Text;
    }
    string sqlinsert = "insert into tblmiddaymeal_receipt(receiptno,studentcode,date,forMonthOf,branch,amount,paymenttype,bankname) "
                 + "values('" + lblreceiptno.Text + "','" + drpstudent.SelectedItem.Value + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "','" + months + "','" + lblbranch.Text + "','" + lblamount.Text + "','" + lblpaymenttype.Text + "','" + lblbankname.Text + "')";
    obj.executeQuery(sqlinsert, Session["schoolcode"].ToString());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean one user interface design with different data value?
may be like this?
First you create constructor, to show the panel format, simple example:

```
Panel myPanel = new Panel();
Label myLabel = new Label();

private void drawMe()
{
this.controls.add(mypanel);
mypanel.controls.add(mylabel);
}

private void forStudent()
{
 mylabel.text = "Student Copy";
}
private void forOffice()
{
 mylabel.text = "Office Copy";
}
private void forAccount()
{
 mylabel.text = "Account Copy";
}
```

Comment: you mean i have to make the panel dynamically,actually i have made my panel pnlreceipt in aspx page,should i paste that code also?

Comment: that's up to you, for what i get from your question is that you want to change the heading only, just create method to change the heading text then

Comment: actually i just want that i load all the data in my pnlreceipt and just make its three copies so that it can be fast also and can be displayed as shown above

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly different.
I think you can use "Usercontrols" available in .net

Then you will be able to do it more dynamically.

Good Luck

Comment: can you please help me in that,i mean where should i bind data because i cant bind in usercontrol page as i have to bind data depending on user selection